# Design a Generic Product Processor

Tags: c#, interface, architecture, asp.net-mvc-5, abstract-class

i'm trying to put some order into a large application that manage Products from **multiple sources**, all of them different from each other but mapped into a single table (NEEDED VALUES).

I'm looking to hear opinions, experiences, patterns or any kind of recommendations.

Let's say we have Product_A,Product_B,Product_C all mapped to "Product_Dto" and saved as Product into SQL (right now different methods, different classes and files)

```
/// <summary>
/// INACCESIBLE TO DEVELOPERS
/// </summary>
public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int status_id { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public List<int> quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Product_Dto
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int? status_id { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
}
```

The main idea is to reorganize (rewrite) the code and provide an abstract class that must be implemented every time they need to add a new Product source.

Why abstract class? Some of the points

- We want to hide functionality that apply to all sources (Private methods)
- We want to provide functionality that developers will need when implementing a new source (Public or Protected methods)
- We want to ensure developers write some NEEDED code (Abstract methods)
- We want to give the possibility to implement custom code in certain scenarios (Virtual methods)

As i mentioned, the application manage the products from multiple sources and **some of the information must be processed, formatted and mapped** by executing multiple PRIVATE methods *that nobody can touch, override, etc* (business logics and value assignment by lookup other lists and sources) and this is the biggest problem i found.

Resuming:

- Create Abstract Class: ok
- Add Private,Public and Abstract Methods: OK
- Map Products_A to Product_Dto manually applying logic: OK => GetProduct_Dto(Product_A product)
- Map Products_B to Product_Dto manually applying logic: OK => GetProduct_Dto(Product_B product)
- Create a Generic Mapper: NOT OK => GetProduct_Dto(Product_Generic product);

**If write the custom Dto for each case with real Product types work, take that way!**

Ok, but for some reason i didn't like it.

We're talking about map at least 60 properties for each source. 90% of the properties had different database values than the original (status, type, category, etc etc) so the value comes from a private function (that will be the same for all scenarios).
Also Product class (DB) changes frequently and properties must be added to each source / mapping and make sure the right function is being used for new ones, without interface its impossible. (ONLY CREATE, x2 FOR UPDATE that had the same properties / functionality with exception of some insert values like created_date, sku, that will never change).

**Workaround => Generic Mapper: The Interface Way**

Ok, to create a generic Mapper we can implement an Interface, let's call it IProduct and Product_A,Product_B & Product_C must implement it. Then, we can write a new GetProduct_Dto

```
public interface IProduct
{
    //INTERFACES CANNOT CONTAIN INSTANCE CONSTRUCTORS (to assign source on new)
    //public IProduct(Product_Source_Enum source)
    //{
    //    this.source = source;
    //}

    public Product_Source_Enum source { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    public enum Product_Source_Enum
    {
        A,
        B,
        C
    }
}

public class Product_A : IProduct
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public ProductA_Status_Enum status { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    public string description_text { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }


    public IProduct.Product_Source_Enum source { get; set; } = IProduct.Product_Source_Enum.A;
    int IProduct.id { get { if (int.TryParse(this.id, out int ID)) { return ID; } return 0; } set => this.id = value.ToString(); }
    string IProduct.name { get => this.title; set => this.title = value; }
    string IProduct.status { get => this.status.ToString(); set { if (Enum.TryParse<ProductA_Status_Enum>(value, out ProductA_Status_Enum STATUS)) { this.status = STATUS; } } }
    string IProduct.category { get => this.category_name; set => this.category_name = value; }
    string IProduct.description { get => this.description_text; set => this.description_text = value; }


    public enum ProductA_Status_Enum
    {
        active,
        inactive
    }
}

public class Product_B : IProduct
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public ProductB_Status_Enum general_status { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }


    public IProduct.Product_Source_Enum source { get; set; } = IProduct.Product_Source_Enum.B;
    int IProduct.id { get => this.id; set => this.id = value; }
    string IProduct.name { get => this.name; set => this.name = value; }
    string IProduct.status { get => this.general_status.ToString(); set { if (Enum.TryParse<ProductB_Status_Enum>(value, out ProductB_Status_Enum STATUS)) { this.general_status = STATUS; } } }
    string IProduct.category { get => this.category; set => this.category = value; }
    string IProduct.description { get => this.description; set => this.description = value; }
    decimal IProduct.price { get => this.price; set => this.price = value; }


    public enum ProductB_Status_Enum
    {
        enabled,
        disabled,
        paused
    }
}
```

1. Create a IProduct Interface: OK
2. Implement IProduct in Product_A,Product_B & Product_C: OK
3. Write the GetProduct_Dto(IProduct product): **OK, BUT CASTING**

**What's the problem about map the Interface IProduct to Product_Dto?**

I will need all values of all sources merged into the interface in order to maintain the current functionality and map the values into the Product_Dto internally (private mapping)*

- FALSE => Casting from IProduct to Product_A, Product_B, Product_C will solve the problem.

Resume

- Implement IProduct Interface fits perfect to fill the Product_Dto because only basic needed properties will be included, keeping the interface small.

  ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Private Mapping between Interface object and Product_Dto
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="product"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   private Product_Dto GetProduct_Dto(IProduct product)
   {
       return new Product_Dto
       {
           category_id = GetCategory(product.category),
           description = product.description,
           id = product.id,
           name = product.name,
           price = product.price,
           status_id = GetStatus(product.status)
       };
   }
  ```

**FULL ABSTRACT CLASS**

```
public abstract class ProductProcessor
{

    private Database _db = new Database();

    /// <summary>
    /// Private Mapping between Interface object and Product_Dto
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="product"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Product_Dto GetProduct_Dto(IProduct product)
    {
        return new Product_Dto
        {
            category_id = GetCategory(product.category),
            description = product.description,
            id = product.id,
            name = product.name,
            price = product.price,
            status_id = GetStatus(product.status)
        };
    }

    protected Product_Dto Create(IProduct product)
    {
        var productDto = GetProduct_Dto(product);
        var productDb = new Product();
        _db.Product.Add(productDb);
        _db.SetValues(productDb, productDto);

        //private method, different logics for every type but still PRIVATE
        //DEVELOPERS CAN'T DECIDE WAT HAPPEN HERE
        Create_Depot_With_Stock(productDb, product); //=> CAST WILL BE NEEDED TO ACCESS FULL OBJECT

        //Create function has a lot of private functions, casting will be needed for each function

        //Other_1(productDb, product); //=> CAST WILL BE NEEDED TO ACCESS FULL OBJECT =====> EXCESIVE CASTING???
        //Other_2(productDb, product); //=> CAST WILL BE NEEDED TO ACCESS FULL OBJECT =====> EXCESIVE CASTING???
        //Other_3(productDb, product); //=> CAST WILL BE NEEDED TO ACCESS FULL OBJECT =====> EXCESIVE CASTING???

        _db.SaveChanges();
        return productDto;
    }

    public Product_Dto Update(IProduct product)
    {
        var productDb = _db.Find(product.sku);
        var productDto = GetProduct_Dto(product);
        _db.SetValues(productDb, productDto);

        //private method, different logics for every type but still PRIVATE
        //DEVELOPERS CAN'T DECIDE WAT HAPPEN HERE
        Update_Source_Quantity(product, productDb); //=> CAST WILL BE NEEDED TO ACCESS FULL OBJECT

        //Other_1(productDb, product); //=> CAST WILL BE NEEDED TO ACCESS FULL OBJECT =====> EXCESIVE CASTING???
        //Other_2(productDb, product); //=> CAST WILL BE NEEDED TO ACCESS FULL OBJECT =====> EXCESIVE CASTING???
        //Other_3(productDb, product); //=> CAST WILL BE NEEDED TO ACCESS FULL OBJECT =====> EXCESIVE CASTING???


        Update_Source_Quantity_WORKAROUND(product); //MUST BE OVERRIDED AND CASTED BY DEVELOPERS

        _db.SaveChanges();
        return productDto;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private method, developer must implement the interface properties and here we process the values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="status"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private int GetCategory(string status)
    {
        var statuses = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            { "none",0 },
            { "CatA",1 },
            { "CatB" ,2},
            { "CatC",3 }
        };

        if (statuses.ContainsKey(status))
            return statuses.GetValueOrDefault(status);

        return 0;
    }

    private int? GetStatus(string status)
    {
        var statuses = new Dictionary<string, int> {
            { "other",0 },
            { "active",1 },
            { "inactive" ,2},
            { "enabled",3 },
            { "disabled",4 },
            { "paused",5 } };

        if (statuses.ContainsKey(status))
            return statuses.GetValueOrDefault(status);

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// EVERY METHOD THAT NEED THE FULL PRODUCT WILL NEED TO CAST THE IProduct
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="productDb"></param>
    /// <param name="product"></param>
    private void Create_Depot_With_Stock(Product productDb, IProduct product)
    {
        int product_stock = 0;// product.quantity doesnt exists in interface WE MUST CAST TYPES

        if (product.source == IProduct.Product_Source_Enum.A)
        {
            var product_a = (Product_A)product;
            product_stock = product_a.quantity;
            productDb.quantity = new List<int> { product_stock };
            return;
        }

        if (product.source == IProduct.Product_Source_Enum.B)
        {
            var product_a = (Product_A)product;
            product_stock = product_a.quantity;
            productDb.quantity = new List<int> { product_stock };
            return;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OUTSIDE DEVELOPERS DONT NEED TO KNOW THIS IS HAPPENING
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="product"></param>
    /// <param name="productDb"></param>
    private void Update_Source_Quantity(IProduct product, Product productDb)
    {
        if (product is Product_A)
        {
            var product_a = (Product_A)product;
            //THIS IF IS THE SAME FOR EVERY Product Type, EXTRACT FUNCTION AND USE VALUES?
            if (product_a.quantity != productDb.quantity.Sum())
            {
                //do something
            }
            return;
        }

        if (product is Product_B)
        {
            var product_b = (Product_B)product;
            //THIS IF IS THE SAME FOR EVERY Product Type, EXTRACT FUNCTION AND USE VALUES?
            if (product_b.quantity != productDb.quantity.Sum())
            {
                //do something
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    protected abstract void Update_Source_Quantity_WORKAROUND(IProduct product);

}
```

- **What i didn't like**: when need to find the database value for a property (via private function) the function will accept a string generic parameter for status instead of the enum (but nobody will die).

  ```
   private int? GetStatus(string status)
   {
       var statuses = new Dictionary<string, int> {
           { "other",0 },
           { "active",1 },
           { "inactive" ,2},
           { "enabled",3 },
           { "disabled",4 },
           { "paused",5 } };

       if (statuses.ContainsKey(status))
           return statuses.GetValueOrDefault(status);

       return null;
   }
  ```
- I can't find an easy way to transport full Product_A,B & C to the base to manage them in his right type (this would make everything easier) Ex. Product.status = Product_A.Status_Enum.active and not a status in string.

- FALSE AGAIN => Casting from IProduct to Product_A, Product_B, Product_C will solve the problem.

  ```
    /// <summary>
    /// EVERY METHOD THAT NEED THE FULL PRODUCT WILL NEED TO CAST THE IProduct
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="productDb"></param>
    /// <param name="product"></param>
    private void Create_Depot_With_Stock(Product productDb, IProduct product)
    {
        int product_stock = 0;// product.quantity doesn't exists in interface WE MUST CAST TYPES

        if (product.source == IProduct.Product_Source_Enum.A)
        {
            var product_a = (Product_A)product;
            product_stock = product_a.quantity;
            productDb.quantity = new List<int> { product_stock };
            return;
        }

        if (product.source == IProduct.Product_Source_Enum.B)
        {
            var product_a = (Product_A)product;
            product_stock = product_a.quantity;
            productDb.quantity = new List<int> { product_stock };
            return;
        }
    }
  ```

**Some unresolved questions:**

1. Im using the source attribute only to cast the Product into its original type. since INTERFACES CANNOT CONTAIN INSTANCE CONSTRUCTORS assign the source is in hands of developers. **Any workaround?**

   ```
    //public IProduct(Product_Source_Enum source)
    //{
    //    this.source = source;
    //}
   ```

**AUTO RESPONSE 1**: Converting the interface into an abstract class may work. any ideas?

2. What about cast the Interface every time i need the concrete class? There is a lot of IFS for every method only for casting purposes. **Any ideas how to handle?**

   ```
    /// <summary>
    /// EVERY METHOD THAT NEED THE FULL PRODUCT WILL NEED TO CAST THE IProduct
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="productDb"></param>
    /// <param name="product"></param>
    private void Create_Depot_With_Stock(Product productDb, IProduct product)
    {
        int product_stock = 0;// product.quantity doesnt exists in interface WE MUST CAST TYPES

        if (product.source == IProduct.Product_Source_Enum.A)
        {
            var product_a = (Product_A)product;
            product_stock = product_a.quantity;
            productDb.quantity = new List<int> { product_stock };
            return;
        }

        if (product.source == IProduct.Product_Source_Enum.B)
        {
            var product_a = (Product_A)product;
            product_stock = product_a.quantity;
            productDb.quantity = new List<int> { product_stock };
            return;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OUTSIDE DEVELOPERS DONT NEED TO KNOW THIS IS HAPPENING
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="product"></param>
    /// <param name="productDb"></param>
    private void Update_Source_Quantity(IProduct product, Product productDb)
    {
        if (product is Product_A)
        {
            var product_a = (Product_A)product;
            //THIS IF IS THE SAME FOR EVERY Product Type, EXTRACT FUNCTION AND USE VALUES?
            if (product_a.quantity != productDb.quantity.Sum())
            {
                //do something
            }
            return;
        }

        if (product is Product_B)
        {
            var product_b = (Product_B)product;
            //THIS IF IS THE SAME FOR EVERY Product Type, EXTRACT FUNCTION AND USE VALUES?
            if (product_b.quantity != productDb.quantity.Sum())
            {
                //do something
            }
            return;
        }
    }
   ```